# Component with same height

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to make a LinearLayout have the same height as a TextView?

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="16dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@color/blue"/>

<ImageView
  android:layout_width="20dp"
  android:layout_height="20dp"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/edit"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar"
  android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_nome"
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
  android:text="Titulo"
  android:textSize="12sp"
  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I wanted the

```
android: layout_height = ""
```

From my LinearLayout had the same size as the TextView `lista_personalizada_nome`, remembering that this should be `wrap_content` because the text changes size. Is there a way to do this? I know by size you set a default value, but would have a way to make this value equal to that of TextView, for example?

Edit: TextView can not stay within this LinearLayout

Explaining better:

Everything is inside a cardview, LinearLayout serves as a background for the person's name

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/cli"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="3dp"
  android:background="#FEFEFE"
  app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="16dp"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@color/blue"/>

    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/edit"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar"
      android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_nome"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:text="Titulo"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_celular"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_nome"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:text="celular"
      android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_renda"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_celular"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:text="renda"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_limite"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_renda"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:text="limite"
      android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_bandeira"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_status"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:text="bandeira"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_status"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_limite"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:text="status"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lista_personalizada_id"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lista_personalizada_limite"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lista_curso_personalizada_imagem"
      android:text="id"
      android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: first of all your LinearLayout doesn't have "orientation" attribute. Is it vertical or horizontal?

Comment: @an_droid_dev Can be vertical

Comment: What kind of behavior and look of a layout are you trying to archive here? Because with what you have provided I would say it is impossible unless both `ImageView` visibility is set to `gone` or you put `TextView` into its seperate `LinearLayout`. Maybe there is a better approach to whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @TomasJablonskis Take a look now, explain in a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To archive `LinearLayout` expand when `TextView` grows in size you need to add following attributes to your `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
          ...
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lista_personalizada_nome"
          .../>
```

---

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the text view (and the other components) inside the linear layout.
or (better) give the color attribute to the relative layout and remove the linear layout.

Comment: If I put the color in a relativelayout, how would your heith be the same as the textview? The result would be the same as now, if the name field gets large, it leaves the area with blue background